# Finding duplicates including format with script, grammar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a script to find duplicates in my Google Drive Sheet that are formatted exactly the same. Specifically, there may be duplicate data in a column, but one instance should be red and the other instance should be black. I want to highlight the cells where both instances are black. I have a script to find the duplicates but it highlights them regardless of text color. Thanks for your help.

The script I'm using for finding duplicates is:

```
//================================


function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{name : "Check Duplicates",functionName : "checkDuplicates"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
};

function checkDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("L:L"); // Set Any Range
  // "L:L" is for Columns L
  // And if you want to check duplicates for whole sheet then try this:
  // var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var numRows = data.length;
  var numColumns = data[0].length;

  var formats = [];
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    formats[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
      formats[i][j] = 'WHITE';
      if (data[i][j] != '') {
        values.push([data[i][j], i, j]);
      }
    }
  }
  var numValues = values.length;

  for (var k = 0 ; k < numValues - 1; k++) {
    if (formats[values[k][1]][values[k][2]] == 'WHITE') {
      for (var l = k + 1; l < numValues; l++) {
        if (values[k][0] == values[l][0]) {
          formats[values[k][1]][values[k][2]] = 'YELLOW';
          formats[values[l][1]][values[l][2]] = 'YELLOW';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  dataRange.setBackgroundColors(formats);
}


//================================
```

I'm not familiar with script for Google Drive so I'm not sure how to modify to add the formatting requirement.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlights duplicates in column L where font color is black:
 to be considered a duplicate  cells must have the same value and a font color of black.

```
function checkDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("L1:L" + sheet.getLastRow());
  dataRange.setBackground("white");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var colors = dataRange.getFontColors();
  var numRows = data.length;
  var highlights = dataRange.getBackgrounds();
  for(var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    data[r].push(colors[r][0]);
    data[r].push(r);
  }
  data.sort();
  for(var r = 0; r < data.length - 1; r++) {
    if(data[r][0] && data[r][1] == "#000000") {
      if(data[r][0] == data[r+1][0] && data[r+1][1] == "#000000") {
        highlights[data[r][2]][0] = "yellow";
        highlights[data[r+1][2]][0] = "yellow";
      }
    }
  }
  dataRange.setBackgrounds(highlights);
}
```

If this is not what you intended, let me know.

[image]

L3 & L6 are highlighted. L2 & L5 are not.

Comment: This code is really close to what I was intending. However, I want ONLY duplicates where BOTH instances are formatted black to be highlighted. Here is an example. 
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qMVlNRGo1TYCCKSLsfqu18SkBslrokbBLyUUKKfa_X8/pubhtml)
In the example cell L3 & L6 should be highlighted, but L2 & L5 should not. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please tell me exactly what the code did wrong once you ran it.

Comment: Assuming col L is Addresses in the example link. I copied the data to a spreadsheet, ran the code and it did exactly as expected. L3 and L6 were the only items highlighted.

Comment: I apologize! The code you gave did exactly as intended. I ran the old code by mistake. Thank you so much for your help.